# How to select all rows without references from another model class in GQL?

Tags: google-app-engine, gql, gqlquery

I have

```
class Question(db.Model):
    wording = db.StringProperty(required=True)

class Answer(db.Model):
    question = db.ReferenceProperty(Question, required=True)
    userId = db.IntegerProperty(required=True)
```

And I want to

```
SELECT * FROM Question WHERE Id NOT IN (
       SELECT QuestionId FROM Answer WHERE userId = 1)
```

How to do that in GQL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GQL doesn't have a `NOT IN` statement, so unfortunately, it's not possible to do exactly what you want.

If the total set of userIds is small, you can reverse your query to use the `IN` statement. For instance:

```
SELECT * FROM Answer WHERE userId IN ('2', '3')
```

Note that this is executing a subquery for each value in the `IN` statement and you are allowed a maximum of 30 queries per GQL statement.

If the total set of Answers where `userId = 1` is small, you can select all Answers and filter out the ones from `userId = 1` in your own code. However, if the set of Answers from userId 1 is large, this will not be particularly efficient.

Finally, rather than computing either of these queries on-demand, you can use a cron to precompute the results (and store them to the datastore and/or memcache). When your code requires the results of one of these queries, you can load the cached result.